# Button binding not working

Tags: silverlight, button, telerik-grid, radgridview

I've **RadButton** control in **RadGridView** and its functionality is same like a toggle button (to open a nested gird).

```
<telerik:RadButton x:Name="expand" Width="20" Content="+" Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Click="btnExpand_Click" />
```

And "**btnExpand_Click**" functionality is

```
 private void btnExpand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadButton btn = sender as RadButton;
        if (btn.Content.Equals("+") && flagRowSelected == true)
        {
            flagRowSelected = false;
            if (signButton != null)
            {

                signButton.Content = "+";
            }
            btn.Content = "-";
            grd.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;

        }
        else
        {

            flagRowSelected = true;
            btn.Content = "+";
            grd.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;

        }
        signButton = btn;
    }
```

I'm facing two issues over here.

1) I select any row explicitly and then click on **"+"** button. This code works fine and its nested grid becomes visible but button content does not change to **"-"**.

2) And if I don't select any row explicitly and click on **"+"** button. This code does not work and its nested grid does not become visible.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is "signButton"? Is it merely to store the state of your button, whether it currently displays + or -?

Comment: Its a button that stores last button's state. It stores correct values.

Comment: I used sdk dataGrid and my issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can see several issues with the code, not sure where to start. Let's start with the signButton: you set it as the last statement (and at one point even set its content before), but you never read it again. So there is no point in having the signButton. And if you need to store whether the RowDetails are expanded why not use a bool?

Second: you set the rowDetailsVisibility to `VisibleWhenSelected` therefore when no row is selected the click on the button won't show the rowDetails.

Third: Why do you even use a RadButton in the first place? You need a Button with two distinct states, so a `ToggleButton` seems to be the natural choice.

From the xaml line you show I reason that you provide some kind of custom template for the grid, maybe a row template, so I assume you are free to use any control for the RowDetails expander button?

Ok, maybe there is no real benefit from using a ToggleButton, not sure.

I altered your code, maybe you have a look at this and try this out:

```
private void btnExpand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonBase btn = sender as ButtonBase;
    if (btn.Content.Equals("+"))
    {
        btn.Content = "-";
        grd.RowDetailsVisibilityMode =
            GridViewRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;
        var correspondingRow = btn.GetAncestor<GridRow>();
        correspondingRow.Selected = true;

    }
    else
    {

        btn.Content = "+";
        grd.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = GridViewRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;

    }
}
```

Finding an ancestor of a certain type:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static TAncestor GetAncestor<TAncestor>( this DependencyObject subElement )
        where TAncestor : DependencyObject
    {
        return subElement.GetAncestor<TAncestor>( potentialAncestorToStopTheSearch: null );
    }

    public static TAncestor GetAncestor<TAncestor>( this DependencyObject subElement, UIElement potentialAncestorToStopTheSearch )
        where TAncestor : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent;
        for (DependencyObject subControl = subElement; subControl != null; subControl = parent)
        {
            if (subControl is TAncestor) return (TAncestor) subControl;

            if (object.ReferenceEquals( subControl, potentialAncestorToStopTheSearch )) return null;


            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( subControl );
            if (parent == null)
            {
                FrameworkElement element = subControl as FrameworkElement;
                if (element != null)
                {
                    parent = element.Parent;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright. Lets start from 2nd point, when I click on button in row, isn't that row automatically selected?

Comment: Should not I find corresponding row first, and then make it visible?

Comment: Answeriung your first comment: That depends on the GridView control. The DataGrid (provided by microsoft inside the base libs for Silverlight) will select any row automatically when you click a Button inside the row. I don't know the telerik GridView behavior. You have one in your UI, why not try it out and click on a button and see if the row gets selcted?

Comment: I've telerik grid view and here it does not select row automatically.

Comment: Make the row visible? When the user clicks it I assume it already is visible.

Comment: And there's no option of "FindAncestor"

Comment: So now we have clarified the row selection behavior: when the button is clicked you have to select the row from inside you event handler, otherwise it will not be selected.

Comment: Now "how to find the correspondingRow"? Give me a few minutes to find the correct helper methods, or you google for them, try google for `VisualTreeHelper`

Comment: Okay sure I try googling this one

Comment: ooops martin, thats too long. I did it by using.."var correspondingRow = btn.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();"

Comment: OK, I added the code I usually use to find ancestors. It is "tried and trusted".
I am not sure about the row type that is used inside the telerik GridView. Maybe it is "GridRow" but it could also be "RadGridRow" or similar.

Comment: Issues are still there -_-

Comment: @NailaAkbar: I recommend a completely different approach. What you want is an Expander per row that allows the user to click open the rowDetails as he wishes. The RowDetailsVisibilityMode property of the telerik GridView may not offer such an option. Take a look into the control template an search for the row details presenter, how is its visibility bound? maybe you can just set a property on the GridViewRow control to switch it to visible?

Comment: Thanks for your help martin. I've resolved this issue by using sdk grid instead of telerik.